# rails_admin how to include a child attribute in create form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I'm trying to make a form to create new record for a model user which has one `billing_information`. `Billing_information` has an attribute `account_name` that I want to include in the form. I tried using the delegate method but it's not working. It produces :-

> error: unknown attribute 'billing_information_account_name' for User.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :billing_information
   has_one :billing_information, inverse_of: :user
   delegate :account_name, to: :billing_information, allow_nil: true

   rails_admin do
      create do
         field :name
         field :email
         field :billing_information_account_name do
            def value
               bindings[:object].account_name    
            end
         end
      end
   end
end
```

Does anyone has a better solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, you won't get help from rails admin in this case, but it can be done.

You have to add a new virtual field and handle in a setter the input. Take a look at this example.

```
  class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :billing_information, inverse_of: :user

    # A getter used to populate the field value on rails admin
    def billing_information_account_name
      billing_information.account_name
    end

    # A setter that will be called with whatever the user wrote in your field
    def billing_information_account_name=(name)
      billing_information.update(account_name: name)
    end

    rails_admin do
      configure :billing_information_account_name, :text do
        virtual?
      end

      edit do
        field :billing_information_account_name
      end
    end
  end
```

You can always create the full billing_information using the nested attributes strategy, meaning add the billing_information field and you'll get a nice form to fill all the information.